# Loops inside react components leading to rendering of sub components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data as below

```
myArr = [
  {
    "Sl.No": "n1",
    company: "ABC",
    Name: "Sam",
    Designation: "Architect",
    Salary: "100",
  },
  {
    "Sl.No": "n2",
    company: "ABC",
    Name: "Bill",
    Designation: "Engineer",
    Salary: "200",
  },
  {
    "Sl.No": "n3",
    company: "ABC",
    Name: "Jill",
    Designation: "HR",
    Salary: "300",
  },
  {
    "Sl.No": "n4",
    company: "XYZ",
    Name: "Bill",
    Designation: "Engineer",
    Salary: "250",
  },
  {
    "Sl.No": "n5",
    company: "XYZ",
    Name: "Tom",
    Designation: "Mechanic",
    Salary: "150",
  },
  {
    "Sl.No": "n6",
    company: "LMN",
    Name: "Tom",
    Designation: "Mechanic",
    Salary: "150",
  },
];
```

I want to create a react app which shows the data as below. Nothing but listing the employees & their designations under the name of the company.

The boxes on the right are number of doses of vaccine taken (data comes from somewhere else)

[image]

I have the components set-up like so

**Inside App.js**
I have left out importing the components , css & all that for simplcity

```
export const App = () => {
return (
    <div className=app}>
      <CompanyInfo />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Inside CompanyInfo.js**

```
export const CompanyInfo= () => {

let companies= [...new Set(myArr.map((item) => item.company))];

  const renderingComponents = (company: string, index: number) => {
    return (
      <Fragment key={index}>
        <p className="company-name">{company}</p>
        <div className="category-employees">
          <CompanyEmployee toggled={toggled} />
        </div>
        ;
      </Fragment>
    );
  };

return (
    <div className=company-info}>
       {companies.map((item, index) => renderingComponents(item, index))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

So far, so good, I can render the titles of all the companies & I have hardcoded the `CompanyEmployee` to see if it populates within every company & it does. However, I want `CompanyEmployee` to be dynamic & I am not able to figure our how to pass the company related info to the components (that data will have info of all the company employees) and then map the `CompanyEmployee` component on that data.

**Inside CompanyEmployee.js**

Please note that this is like a wrapper for 2 components

```
export const CompanyEmployee= () => {
return (
    <div className=ce}>
      <EmployeePrimaryDetails />
      <EmployeeVacDetails />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Inside EmployeePrimaryDetails.js**

```
export const EmployeePrimaryDetails= (props) => {
return (
    <div className=epd>
      <span className="name">{props.Name}</span>
      <span className="designation">{props.Designation}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can anyone guide me on how I render `EmployeePrimaryDetails.js` for each employee of the company?
I tried to do a `for of`, `forEach`, `map` in the `renderingComponents` function of `CompanyInfo` itself but when I try that I get the Typescript error "Expression Expected" (I am using typescript with React in my project).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Am I mistaken in thinking that at first glance you aren't passing any props into `EmployeePrimaryDetails`? Shouldn't you have `<EmployeePrimaryDetails Name={name} Designation={designation} />` and then obviously you need to pass them into `<CompanyEmployee />` from `CompanyInfo`

Comment: Brett, yes, I should be passing props. I am just not able to figure out in `companyinfo`. Once I figure out there, I will update the components. If the structure i have does not work, I may have to change it, hence I start with hard coding & go one by one from the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `renderingComponents` function you can say:

```
const filteredList = myArr.filter(employee => employee.company === company);
filteredList.map(employee => (<CompanyEmployee employee={employee} toggled={toggled} />));
```

Resulting in this:

```
const renderingComponents = (company: string, index: number) => {
const filteredList = myArr.filter(employee => employee.company === company);
    return (
      <Fragment key={index}>
        <p className="company-name">{company}</p>
        <div className="category-employees">
          {filteredList.map(employee => (<CompanyEmployee employee={employee} toggled={toggled} />))}
        </div>
        ;
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
```

So in `CompanyEmployee` component you can destructure the data you need.

Comment: Máté Wiszt, Thanks for the solution. It Worked.